# Managing a project with header-only libs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

Right now I am having a project which uses a templated, hence header-only, library, and builds two apps.

My folder organisation is as follows :

```
base/lib
base/app1
base/app2
```

What I do right now is that I have `base/lib/lib.pri` which looks like :

```
HEADERS += ../lib/someHeader.h
```

And I include it in `base/app1/app1.pro` and `base/app2/app2.pro`.

However, in QtCreator, it looks somewhat ugly, for two reasons :

- The path in the `.pri` file depends on where it is included from. For instance, if I had another app that for some reason I wanted to be in folder `anotherBase/app3/` it would not work.
- On the project tree it looks like :

(looks like I have to put text after a list in order to have code pretty-print)

```
app1
  -> app1.pro
  -> headers
  -> source files
  -> lib/
       -> lib.pri
       -> headers
           -> someHeader.h
app2
  -> app2.pro
  -> headers
  -> source files
  -> lib/
       -> lib.pri
       -> headers
           -> someHeader.h
```

Hence I have two times the library files in the tree view.

Is there any way to optimize this ? I would like to have :

```
app1
  -> app1.pro
  -> headers
  -> source files
app2
  -> app2.pro
  -> headers
  -> source files
lib
  -> lib.pri
  -> headers
```

in the tree view, however if I assing a `.pro` to `lib` and make it its own project, then when I want to compile everything it will complain that there is nothing to compile for lib and make an error...

Thanks!

Comment: What compiler do you use? I tried to make a `TEMPLATE = lib` .pro-file, and looks like gcc 4.4 does not complain about "nothing to compile" - it just produces an empty library in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.pri` file, you should reference all paths to `$$PWD`. This variable contains the full path of the currently parsed file - namely, your include file.

Note that `PWD` has different meaning than `_PRO_FILE_PWD_`, even if they occasionally return the same value.

Comment: Doesn't this only resolve the "The path in the .pri file depends on where it is included from" issue, but not the issue of wanting "lib" to appear as a subproject at the same level as the others in the project tree?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I've found a workaround for the problem. It's kind of a hack, but it works well.
You can make a separate .pro file for your headers-only lib and specify `TEMPLATE = subdirs` for it, but leave `SUBDIRS` variable unassigned. List the headers of the library in this .pro-file. It will look something like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
HEADERS += h1.h \
           h2.h
```

qmake will now understand that this .pro file should not produce any "target", but qt creator will show all headers you listed in the project tree so you can edit them as ordinary project' s headers. And the library will enter the project tree only once and at the appropriate tree level.

Comment: Alas, I think it would be a fine solution for standard C++ projects, however I have some Qt objects defined on my headers... With the solution from @Kuba Oder, moc is run on the header files, but not here, so many symbols are not defined when linking.